# Managing Color Data in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, shader

Rather than repeating the same color data over and over again for every vertex, how to I apply the color to every vertex? I'm storing the vertex position and texture coordinates all in one buffer, since they vary, but I want the colors to be the same. 
Here's how I'm defining one vertex:

```
vertexData[++vOffset] = position.x;
vertexData[++vOffset] = position.y;
vertexData[++vOffset] = position.z;
vertexData[++vOffset] = texture.x;
vertexData[++vOffset] = texture.y;
vertexData[++vOffset] = r;
vertexData[++vOffset] = g;
vertexData[++vOffset] = b;
vertexData[++vOffset] = a;
```

I tried storing RGBA in one float buffer and applying it like so:

```
vertexBuffer.position(0);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLShader.mPositionHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLShader.mPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 36, vertexBuffer);

vertexBuffer.position(3);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLShader.mTexCoordLoc);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLShader.mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 36, vertexBuffer);

colorBuffer.position(0);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLShader.mColorHandle);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(GLShader.mColorHandle, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, colorBuffer);
```

Also, how do I set up the shader so that if there's no color input, it's defaulted to (1,1,1,1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options. The most obvious one is that you use a `uniform` instead of an `attribute` value for the color. The declaration in the fragment shader code could look like this:

```
uniform vec4 Color;
```

Then you set the color with one of the `glUniform*()` calls, like:

```
// One time, after shader has been linked.
int colorLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(progId, "Color");

// Every time you want to change color.
GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorLoc, colorR, colorG, colorB);
```

However, you can also keep using an attribute, and set it to a constant value using:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttrib4f(GLShader.mColorHandle, colorR, colorG, colorB);
```

To use this, the corresponding vertex array has to be disabled. So if you previously enabled it, you will need to disable it:

```
GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLShader.mColorHandle);
```